# why does if("string") evaluate "string" as true but if ("string"==true) does not?

Tags: javascript

Given the following code:

```
if ("string") {
    console.log('true!');
}
//logs "true" to the console
if ("string"==true) {
    console.log('true!');
}
//doesn't log anything
```

Why does this happen? I thought `"string"` was being cast to a number, as is the boolean. So `true` becomes `1`, and `"string"` becomes `NaN`. The second if statement makes sense, but I don't see why the first statement causes the inner loop to be evaluated. What's going on here?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It is being cast to Boolean. Any non-empty string evaluates to true.

From the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf):

> ### 12.5 The `if` statement
>
> #### Semantics
>
> The production *IfStatement*: `if (` *Expression* `)` *Statement* `else` *Statement* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *exprRef* be the result of evaluating *Expression*.
> 2. If ToBoolean(GetValue(*exprRef*)) is **true**, then
>
>    - Return the result of evaluating the first *Statement*.
> 3. Else,
>
>    - Return the result of evaluating the second *Statement*.
>
> ### 9.2 ToBoolean
>
> The abstract operation ToBoolean converts its argument to a value of type Boolean according to Table 11:
>
> #### Table 11 - ToBoolean Conversions
>
> Undefined: **false**
>   Null: **false**
>   Boolean: The result equals the input argument (no conversion).
>   Number: The result is **false** if the argument is **+0**, **-0**, or **NaN**; otherwise the result is **true**.
>   String: The result is **false** if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); 
>   otherwise the result is **true**.
>   Object: **true**

---

As far as the `==` operator is concerned, it's complicated, but the gist of it is that if you compare a number to a non-number the latter is converted into a number. If you compare a boolean against a non-boolean, the boolean is first converted to a number, and then the previous sentence applies.

See section 11.9.3 for details.

```
// Call this x == y.
if ("string" == true) 

// Rule 6: If Type(y) is Boolean,
//         return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
if ("string" == Number(true))

// Rule 5: If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number,
//         return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.  
if (Number("string") == Number(true))

// The above is equivalent to:
if (NaN == 1)

// And NaN compared to *anything* is false, so the end result is:
if (false)
```

Comment: Touché. +1 for finding the exact case.

Comment: Does the toNumber method only apply for == then?

Answer (score 9):

Non-empty strings are truthy, but are not necessarily equivalent to `true`.

---

`==` is a "soft" equality operator.
It uses type coercion to compare two equivalent objects as equal.

All of the following are true:

```
42 == "42"
0 == false
0 == ""
[] == ""
{} == "[object Object]"
"1" == true
```

Aribtrary strings are not equivlant to any primitive values.
However

---

When you write `if (something)`, the `if` will execute if `something` is "truthy".

All values are truthful except the following:

- `false`
- `0`
- `NaN`
- `""`
- `null`
- `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

```
if ("string"===true)
```

Should be written this way.

Answer (score 0):

"string" is a string which is not null. In JavaScript everything not being null evaluates "true". So: if("string") is the same as if("string" != null) but "string" is not true, it is still a string value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because in the first example, your "string" is a non-null object, which translates to true in this context, whereas in the second example, you're asking if this String object is the same as the Boolean object, which it's not, so it translates to false.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ("string") {
    console.log('true!');
}
```

As you may already know, if evaluates a boolean expression. So it checks

```
if((Boolean)"string")
```

Since (bool)string is true it passes. But in the case of

```
if ("string"==true) {
    console.log('true!');
}
```

You are trying to equate a string with a bool, which obviously compares them and returns false.

Answer (score 0):

From the ECMA 262 reference, if you convert implicitly a String to Boolean, and the String is other than the empty String, it will evaluate to true.

Check [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

`if("string")` is evaluated as a boolean. Any value that isn't `false` is `true`, no conversion to number or anything of that sort.

Comparing `"string"` to a boolean value `true` will obviously yield `false`.