# Increasing understanding of the AND operator

Tags: javascript

I have been using [MDN Docs - Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) as a frame of reference to understand the logical AND operator.

I have understood most of these code examples especially the first 4 as shown here:

```
a1=true && true       // t && t returns true
a2=true && false      // t && f returns false
a3=false && true      // f && t returns false
a4=false && (3 == 4)  // f && f returns false
a5="Cat" && "Dog"     // t && t returns Dog
a6=false && "Cat"     // f && t returns false
a7="Cat" && false     // t && f returns false
```

However I am having issue understanding `a5`, `a6` and `a7`.

I am failing to understand how the two strings `a5="Cat" && "Dog"` are evaluating to `true && true returns Dog`

I am also failing to understand why the string "Cat" is evaluating to true as part of `a6=false && "Cat"     // f && t returns false`

Comment: This has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923631/why-does-ifstring-evaluate-string-as-true-but-if-string-true-does-not

Comment: I have since set out to make sure I have an accepted answer for every question that I ask is this good pratice on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @user1554264 yes it is a good practice, for one it gives me and you some reputation which works as the incentive for people to answer questions, but it also helps others with the same question to find the (in your eyes) best answer. You should ofcourse not accept an answer if there aren't any that correctly answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all lets look at a5:

```
a5="Cat" && "Dog"
```

Which returns `dog`, the mdn-docs states that AND(&&):

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

Since a non-empty string can't be converted to false, it will return `dog`, if you change the order of `dog` and `cat`, it will ofcourse return `cat`.

In a6 false, is false and thus it returns `false` because of this:

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false...

In a7 `cat` is true and thus it goes on to the next expression which is false, and thus returns false.

> ...otherwise, returns expr2

Comment: Yeah a small but significant typo, which i corrected, thanks for pointing that out @Pointy! :)

Answer (score 3):

All non-empty strings are `true` when evaluated as boolean values.

In `a6=false && "Cat"` the string "Cat" is not evaluated at all, as the left side is `false`.

Comment: You are not right. Because the operator is && here, "Cat" will be evaluated too. It wouldn't if the operator was ||. And the end result is correct FALSE (false) and TRUE ("Cat") is FALSE.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp you are not right.  The `&&` operator stops all evaluation once a `false` value is encountered.

Comment: exp1 && exp2 MUST check for both expressions. While, exp1 || exp2 will stop checking after it finds exp1 true.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp I think you should try it out in your browser console, or contemplate the results in the original question, where it clearly says that `false` is the result of that expression.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp consider: if the left side of `&&` is `false`, then what's the point of evaluating the right side?  The whole expression *must* be `false`.

Comment: Yes, a6 and a7 are both false, because in both cases you have TRUE && FALSE. false is false and "Cat" is true.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp no in "a6" the left side is `false`, not `true`.

Comment: In case of &&, the sides don't matter. Only for ||.

Comment: From the documentation linked by Pointy

Logical AND (&&) expr1 && expr2 
Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp well you really should be trying this out in a console; you'll see that you're incorrect. Your own answer states it pretty clearly: in a `&&` expression, "if exp1 does not evaluate to false proceed to exp2".  Sounds pretty clear to me :-)

Comment: All I said, that in case of a chain of && operators, evaluation will never stop while in case of a chain of || operators, evaluation will stop at the first expression that evals to true. You said this the other way round.

Comment: "The && operator stops all evaluation once a false value is encountered" - This is not correct.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp but that's what your own answer says!!

Comment: @MarcellFülöp type this into your browser console right now: `false && alert("Hello Marcell!")`

Comment: Sorry, I realise now that I got it wrong all the time.... My bad. && will stop when false is found, || will stop when true is found.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22766/discussion-between-marcell-fulop-and-pointy)

Answer (score 0):

In `a && b` sentence `a` is evaluated first, and if `a` is `true`, then `b` is evaluated.

1. `(a5 = "Cat")` returns `"Cat"` which is `true` (only empty strings are `false`), so `Dog` is returned.
2. `(a6 = false)` returns `false`, so the second `"Cat"` part is not evaluated.
3. `(a7 = "Cat")` is `true`, so the second `false` part is returned.