# Google Apps Script :: if (<variable that store filter Condition>) does not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

When I run the code as below, it works as what I want.

```
    for(var x in values)
    {
      if (values[x][7] == "ABC")
      {
      filterList.push(values[x]);
      } //end if
    } //end for loop
```

BUT if I assign the filtering condition into variable as below, it does not works as code above.

```
    var filterCondition = 'values[x][7] == "ABC"';

    for(var x in values)
    {
      if (filterCondition)
      {
      filterList.push(values[x]);
      } //end if
    } //end for loop
```

I need this because there are 10 filtering criteria I need to code.
Anyone can help me ? (please tell me there is a way to do it .. XD)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like you're trying to write your `filterCondition` as a macro, which is not supported in javascript. You've defined a string variable, which evaluates as `true` in the `if` statement, simply because the string exists. There's a good explanation of this in the answers to [why does if("string") evaluate "string" as true but if ("string"==true) does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923631/why-does-ifstring-evaluate-string-as-true-but-if-string-true-does-not).

If you are concerned that multiple logic statements will make your if statement difficult to read, you could use a function instead. Let's say that the filter works on a single row at a time. Your code would look like this:

```
function filterCondition(row) {
  return (
    // Amalgamation of filter conditions.
    (row[7] == "ABC") &&
    (row[5] > row[4])     // Keep adding conditions here
  )
}

  ... elsewhere in your code
  for(var x=0; x < values.length; x++)
  {
    if (filterCondition(values[x])) {
      filterList.push(values[x]);
    } //end if
  } //end for loop
```