# FullCalendar events shown in month view only

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar http://fullcalendar.io/ to display some events on a web page.

The calendar is created like this

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        allDayDefault: false,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
   });
```

Events are created through the renderEvent operation (not json feed) like

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent, 'stick');
```

where the newEvent is created like this

```
newEvent = {
                title : 'mytitle',
                start : startDate,
                allDay: false,
                id: eventId,
                description: 'my test event'
            };
```

the problem is that events are correctly shown in month view but are not shown in week or day views.

**UPDATE**

I am using this date format: 2015-02-01T01:00:00

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a jsfiddle that replicates that issue. Thanks!

Comment: What versions of `jQuery` and `fullcalendar` do you use ? how is your `startDate` defined ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've create a [plunker reproducing your code](http://plnkr.co/edit/f2yXiH?p=preview). 
The only problem I see in your code is a comma expected in the creation of the event.

So I create the event with a new moment object -which means now.

```
  var startDate = moment();
  var eventId = 123;
  var newEvent = {
                title : 'mytitle',
                start : startDate,
                allDay: false,
                id: eventId,   //Is this comma that was missing in your code
                description: 'my test event'
            };
```

And I add it with the same code you are doing:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent, 'stick');
```

As you can check in the plunker everything is working fine, so the only problem the code you provide us could have:

- The missing comma.
- The `eventId` variable is wrong
- The `startDate` variable is wrong

In addition, if you take a look at the documentation for [render event](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/) you are not using the 'stick' variable properly. It should be a boolean. In your code is working because as you can check in [line 9229 for version 2.3.1](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/master/dist/fullcalendar.js#L9229) its compared as expression, so any string (non empty) will be true. You can have more info about this in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4923684/2686163

So, if you set the third parameter stick as:

- true
- 'stick'
- 'nonstick'
- 'false'
- 'whatever'

... always be resolved as sticky, and added to the `stickySource`. But, as commented by @slicedtoad, you should change it to avoid problems in future versions.

Comment: Yes, @slicedtoad. It was just an explanation for the reason of having a sticky event even when the stick variable is not use properly.

Comment: The comma was actually present in the original code, the start date is correct as the event is show in the month view and so is (I think) the id. I have seen the plunker works but I can't still understand why it doesn't in my website.

Comment: So @slicedtoad and me reached the same situation. There´s something in your code you didn´t provide us causing that problem.

Comment: @MarioLevrero I'm also having the same problem but mine, it doesn't show the events in days view only. Do you know what seems to be the problem is? thanks

Answer (score 7):

There isn't anything wrong with your code. But you are doing some things in a non-standard way. Try fixing them and the problem might disappear.

The method you are using to add events is not the right one. In FullCalendar terminology, `render` means the process of displaying data to the calendar. So when you `renderEvent`, you are just telling it to *display* an event on screen. And then `stick` makes it persist (kind of).

Instead you should be using [`addEventSource`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/). It can be used to add any event source (local or remote). And an eventSource can be anything from a JSON feed to a local array of one event.

This should work:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource',[{
    title : 'mytitle',
    start : startDate,
    allDay: false,
    id: eventId,
    description: 'my test event'
}]);
```

That gives you  an event that will last for the whole session. It also has the benefit of playing nicely with all the other fullcalendar options and callbacks.

Comment: @lowcoupling Same problem or different one?

Comment: @lowcoupling It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/aLyy0q99/4/), so we're going to need the rest of your FC code.

Comment: @slicedtoad I see you are one of the top users for fullcalendar answers, if you have the time, could you check my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330106/pass-date-params-into-jquery-fullcalendar It is not receiving any repsonses thus far

Comment: The link user2363025 included in the comment doesn't work anymore, because the question was voluntarily removed by its author.

Answer (score 3):

I made [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kwvtfvw/2/) by using your code with some modification from my side. It is working fine. I hope it will work for you. Your inputs are welcomed.

Code

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    fullCalObj = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         header: {
             left: 'prev,next today',
             center: 'title',
             right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
         },
         allDayDefault: false,
         selectable: true,
         selectHelper: true,
         editable: true,
         eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
     });

    var newEvent = {
        title : 'mytitle',
        start : '2015-04-22',
        allDay: false,
        id: 1,
        description: 'my test event'
    };

    fullCalObj.fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent, 'stick');
});
</script>
```