# Buggy binary tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary-tree

I am attempting to solve [codeforces 737A](http://codeforces.com/contest/727/problem/A) using javascript, which is doing a binary search of recrusing the tree of `2*x` and `10*x+1`, from given input `a` to another input `b`, but it seems that my program can only search through those nodes at `2*x`, and those `10*x+1` seems ignored. Interesting and WHY? Thanks.

```
var tt = readline().split(' ');
var a = parseInt(tt[0]);
var b = parseInt(tt[1]);

print(f([],a,b));
function f(arr,x,b){
    if (x>b){
        return [];
    }else if (x==b){
        return _add(arr,x);
    }else{
        return (f(_add(arr,x),(2*x),b) || f(_add(arr,x),(10*x+1),b));
    }
}

function _add(array,x){
    var _arr = array.slice();
    _arr.push(x);
    return _arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `false` instead of an empty array. The empty array resolves to `true` that means you iterate only the left branch.

(BTW, no need for else parts if then parts return.)

```js
function go(a, b) {
    //var tt = readline().split(' ');
    //var a = parseInt(tt[0]);
    //var b = parseInt(tt[1]);

    function f(arr, x, b) {
        if (x > b) {
            return false; // no []!!!
        } 
        if (x == b) {
            return _add(arr, x);
        }
        return (f(_add(arr, x), (2 * x), b) || f(_add(arr, x), (10 * x + 1), b));
    }

    function _add(array, x) {
        var _arr = array.slice();
        _arr.push(x);
        return _arr;
    }

    return f([], a, b);
}
console.log(go(2, 162));
console.log(go(4, 42));
console.log(go(100, 40021));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have never noticed that [] is a truth value in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. Truthiness. In javascript, falsy values are `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `NaN` and empty strings (`""`). All other values are true.

   You are returning an array for the base case:

   ```
   return [];
   ```

   So this will always be true.
2. How the `||` operator works. The `||` operator short-circuits. Therefore, if the left-hand value is truthy it will return it and not evaluate the right-hand code.

   You wrote:

   ```
   f(_add(arr,x),(2*x),b) || f(_add(arr,x),(10*x+1),b)
   ```

   Since in all cases `f()` never return anything falsy that expression is basically:

   ```
   true || f(_add(arr,x),(10*x+1),b)
   ```

   As such the `||` operator never evaluates the `10*x+1` case.

To make the code work you need to either write a function to choose a non-empty array instead of using the `||` operator or make `f()` return false or 0 for the base case instead of an empty array (which may or may not break the algorithm, I don't know since I don't know the algorithm).

Comment: A problem: why ( [] == true ) returns false then?

Comment: Not sure about that but `[]` is indeed truthy: `if ([]) {console.log('HA')}` prints "HA". The `==` operator is probably triggering some type conversion. Note that the `||` operator behaves like `if` rather than `==`: `[] || 'mango'` returns `[]` not "mango" and `[] || console.log('HA')` does not print anything while `[] && console.log('HA')` prints "HA"

Comment: It is interesting, how are `==` in javascript works the

Comment: @MichaelLee: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923631/why-does-ifstring-evaluate-string-as-true-but-if-string-true-does-not