# Javascript: "truthy" values for non-empty strings

Tags: javascript

It's said that non-empty string in Javascript is considered "truthy". It explains why the code:

```
if ("0") { 
    console.log("OK")
}
```

prints "OK".

However, why does the code:

```
true == "0"
```

returns false?

Comment: The `"0"` is coerced to a number in the second case. `true == "1"` for example returns `true`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why does if("string") evaluate "string" as true but if ("string"==true) does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923631/why-does-ifstring-evaluate-string-as-true-but-if-string-true-does-not)

Comment: Any string, other than an empty string, `0`, `false` will be coerced to `true`.

Comment: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Equal (==)
>
> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the
>   operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number
>   or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else
>   if either operand is a string, the other operand is converted to a
>   string if possible. If both operands are objects, then JavaScript
>   compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to
>   the same object in memory.
>
> (From Comparison Operators in Mozilla Developer Network)

So, while comparing `true == '0'`, it first converts both into numbers.

`Number(true) == Number('0')` which evaluates to `1 == 0`.

Hence the answer is false.

Comment: I don't think, that's correct. But, `Number(true)` evaluates to `1`, so if you compare any other value, `true == '2'` it evaluates to `1 == 2` which is false.

Comment: what about null and undefined ?

Comment: `null` and `undefined` both are considered as `false` values in javascript. So if you are talking about `true == null` or `true == undefined`, you can look in either way `true == false` or `1 == 0` ( `Number(null) = 0` ), both will result in false value.

Comment: What happens if we have an object and a string? How do we convert an object to a string?

Comment: In Javascript,` Objects ( {} ) ` are ` true ` values. And, any string other than ```(empty string)` is also true value. To check, you can use `Boolean({})` and `Boolean(`string`)`. To keep it simple, if any of the values in `==` is Number, the values are converted into `Number()`, and for others, it is converted into `Boolean()`.

Comment: @domdomegg That's not true, I just evaluated the following pieces of code, and this is the result. As you can see, the numbers 2 and 3 evaluates to true. `Boolean(0)` -> false, `Boolean(1)` -> true, `Boolean(2)` -> true, `Boolean(3)` -> true. In conclusion, any number that isn't 0 is true in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, I believe `if ("0")` will check if the value is null/empty/undefined, similarly as to if I were to write `if("some text")`, which would also return true. Here `0` is not used as true or false, but rather as a string.

On the other hand, `if(true == "0")` will return false, as the values do not match up.

Here is a snippet showing an if statement returning true on a variable that's not undefined.

```js
var someVar = "0";
if("") {
  console.log("this doesn't execute");
} 
if(someVar) {
  console.log("this returns true");
}
```