# Create localstorage counter depending on variable (no switch function)

Tags: javascript, variables, counter

im just started to learn JavaScript and i´m trying to simplify some code, but couldn´t get a working solution. The working part is this:

```
switch (v) {

            case 0:
            if (localStorage.FGAz0) {
            localStorage.FGAz0 = Number(localStorage.FGAz0)+1;
            } else {
            localStorage.FGAz0 = 1;
            }
            document.getElementById("Ergebnis").innerHTML = "You have " + localStorage.FGAz0+ " Visitor(s).";
            break;  
            case 1:
            if (localStorage.FGAz1) {
            localStorage.FGAz1 = Number(localStorage.FGAz1)+1;
            } else {
            localStorage.FGAz1 = 1;
            }
            document.getElementById("Ergebnis").innerHTML = "You have " + localStorage.FGAz1+ " Visitor(s).";
            break;  
            case 2:
            if (localStorage.FGAz2) {
            localStorage.FGAz2 = Number(localStorage.FGAz2)+1;
            } else {
            localStorage.FGAz2 = 1;
            }
            document.getElementById("Ergebnis").innerHTML = "You have " + localStorage.FGAz2+ " Visitor(s).";   
            break;
            case 3:
            if (localStorage.FGAz3) {
            localStorage.FGAz3 = Number(localStorage.FGAz3)+1;
            } else {
            localStorage.FGAz3 = 1;
            }
            document.getElementById("Ergebnis").innerHTML = "You have " + localStorage.FGAz3+ " Visitor(s).";   
            break;
            case 4:
            if (localStorage.FGAz4) {
            localStorage.FGAz4 = Number(localStorage.FGAz4)+1;
            } else {
            localStorage.FGAz4 = 1;
            }
            document.getElementById("Ergebnis").innerHTML = "You have " + localStorage.FGAz4+ " Visitor(s).";
            break;
            case 5:
            if (localStorage.FGAz5) {
            localStorage.FGAz5 = Number(localStorage.FGAz5)+1;
            } else {
            localStorage.FGAz5 = 1;
            }
            document.getElementById("Ergebnis").innerHTML = "You have " + localStorage.FGAz5+ " Visitor(s).";
            break;
            default: 
            if (localStorage.FahrGastAnzahl) {
            localStorage.FahrGastAnzahl = Number(localStorage.FahrGastAnzahl)+1;
            } else {
            localStorage.FahrGastAnzahl= 1;
            }
            document.getElementById("Ergebnis").innerHTML = "You have " + localStorage.FahrGastAnzahl+ " Visitor(s).";}


    } else {
        document.getElementById("Ergebnis").innerHTML = "Sorry, dein Browser unterstützt die Speicherung von lokalen Daten nicht...";
    }
```

and i am trying to short it to the var depending on "v" which only had numbers. At the moment i have this:

```
if (localStorage.FGAz + "v") {
            (localStorage.FGAz + "v") = Number(localStorage.FGAz + "v")+1; 
        } else {
            (localStorage.FGAz + "v") = 1;
        document.getElementById("Ergebnis").innerHTML = "You have " + (localStorage.FGAz + "v") + " Visitor(s).";}
```

Something isn´t right with the adding of the variable "v", but i don´t know what and didn´t found a solution on searching. Hope someone can help me. Please no jquery, i haven´t learned that yet.

Comment: Working Code: if (localStorage["FGAz" + v.toString()]) {localStorage["FGAz" + v.toString()] = Number(localStorage["FGAz" + v.toString()])+1;} else {localStorage["FGAz" + v.toString()]= 1;}document.getElementById("Ergebnis").innerHTML = "You have " + localStorage["FGAz" + v.toString()] + " Visitor(s)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firs of all**, make sure you understand the difference between `v` and `"v"`:

- `v` is a variable name, which can hold any value (string, number, etc), eg:`v = 1; v = "1"; v = "xxx";`
- `"v"` (mind the brackets) is a string value itself (`v = "v"`, where `v` is the variable name and `"v"` is the variable value). Everything inside the brackets (`"` or `'`) is a string.

*If you wish to cast numerical (integer in this example) value to string, you can use `v.toString()` or simply append an empty string to the value `v + ""`*.

**Secondly**, please get some knowledge on [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

In short: you can access properties of an object in two different ways: using dot notation (`localStorage.FGAz1`) or brackets notation (`localStorage["FGAz1"]`).

Appending string value to dot notated property accessor (`document.getElementBy + "Id"`) will firstly evaluate the value of property (`document.getElementBy` - which evaluates to `undefined`) and THEN will concatenate it with the string (`undefined + "Id"` - which results in  `"undefinedId"`). On the other hand, appending string to accessor value inside bracket notation (`document["getElementBy" + "Id"]`) will firstly evaluate the value of accessor (`"getElementBy" + "Id"` - which evaluates to "getElementById"), and then access the object's property (`document["getElementById"]` - which returns the function).

**Based on your example:**

`localStorage.FGAz` is not defined, so the `localStorage.FGAz + "v"` evaluates to `undefined + "v"` which results in `"undefinedv"` (Notice the 'v' added to the end of 'undefined'). Sentence `if ("undefinedv")` always evaluates to true ([HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923631/why-does-ifstring-evaluate-string-as-true-but-if-string-true-does-not) you can find out why).

**In conclusion:**

Use brackets notation:
`if (localStorage['FGAz' + v.toString()]) {`. This will evaluate to `if (localStorage['FGAz1']) {` for v = 1, `if (localStorage['FGAzXXX']) {` for v = XXX and so on.

*I'm hoping it makes sens to you, if not leave me a question in comments.*

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I knew that it was a problem with the Property Accessors, but didn´t fully unterstand what it was. Now i know. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
localStorage.FGAz + "v"
```

Use

```
localStorage["FGAz" + v]
```

v in `""` quotations makes it a string value not variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the code above and it looks like you're doing some sort of visitor counter. However the `localstorage` would only work for the one person.

If you're going to be doing vistor counter, you could use `ajax` to send the information to a database and then check how many people are online.

Simple visit counter:

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/po2jhz53/)

Code from JSFIDDLE

```
<div id="visitCount"></div>

if (localStorage.visitCount){
  localStorage.visitCount = Number(localStorage.visitCount)+1;
} else {
  localStorage.visitCount = 1;
}

document.getElementById("visitCount").innerHTML = "You've been to this page "+ localStorage.visitCount + " time(s)."
```

Comment: Thx, but this is a option for later. At the moment localStorage is enough.