# for_each inside if_else in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to the coding world, just started learning javascript. Im trying to design a table kind of output but unable to complete it. here is what I am trying to achieve

"Jan - 1 - quarter1" and on second row
"Feb - 2 - quarter1" ...etcetera

I made use of `foreach` , `if/else` and combine them both but couldn't get output maybe because we cannot add a `foreach` inside an if statement or so! can someone help where I am going wrong here?

```js
const Months = ['jan','Feb']

if (Months = 'Jan'||'Apr'||'Jul'||'Sep') {
    Months.forEach(function(Month, index) {
    console.log(`${Month}--${index + 1}`)}
} else {
    console.log(`${Month}--${index + 1}`)
}
```

Comment: Well that if statement is not doing what you think it is doing. It is really unclear what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: What do you expect the following code to do?  `if (Months = 'Jan'||'Apr'||'Jul'||'Sep')`?

Comment: - Strings are case-sensitive. `jan` will never be equal to `Jan`.
 - `=` is for assigning a value. `==` or `===` is to test for equality.
 - Each condition in a multiple condition test must be able to stand on
   its own. `Months == "jan" || "feb", etc. doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty unclear what you're trying to accomplish but I wanted to offer a few things that I saw in your code. Since you are quite new, I understand you may not be super familiar with the language yet.

First, `if (Months = 'Jan'||'Apr'||'Jul'||'Sep')` will always return true no matter what, because you're making three separate mistakes! No worries, let me break them down for you.

The first mistake is that you are using a single equals sign in Months = 'Jan'. The single equals sign is what is known as an ASSIGNMENT operator. You are setting your variable Months equal to the string 'Jan'. What you are looking for is the STRICT EQUALITY operator === which tests to see whether two things are equal.

Please see this for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Your second mistake is that you are looking at the entire Months variable and trying to compare its values against strings. If you had used strict equality like so:

```
if (Months === 'Jan')
```

it still would have failed because Months is an Array. What you need to do is use Months.forEach to iterate over each element of the array, and then do an equality comparison over each month.

Your third mistake is the way you are using the OR operator ||.

Let's look at this code that will have fixed the prior two errors:

```
var months = ['Jan','Feb','Apr','Jul','Sep'];
months.forEach(element => {
  if (element === 'Jan' || 'Feb' || 'Mar'){
    console.log('Gotcha');
  }
});
```

This will still always return true because EACH THING SEPARATE BY THE OR OPERATOR WILL BE EVALUATED INDEPENDENTLY.  In order to properly run your test, you need a separate equality test in each section separated by an OR.

Run the following code snippet and look at the output:

```js
var foo = "Hi";

const test1 = (foo === "Boo" || "You");
const test2 = (foo === "Boo" || foo === "You");    

console.log(test1);
console.log(test2);

if (test1) {
  console.log("This is true??")
}
```

So, what is going on there?

test1 winds up being assigned the value of "You" because the first part evaluates to false, so it assigns the second part.

test2 is false as we would expect.

But what happens if we use an "if" statement on test1, which is currently set to the string "You"?

Take a look at this answer for clarity. [why does if("string") evaluate "string" as true but if ("string"==true) does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923631/why-does-ifstring-evaluate-string-as-true-but-if-string-true-does-not)

At the end of it all, what you want is something like this:

```
var months = ['Jan','Feb','Apr','Jul','Sep'];
months.forEach(element => {
  if (element === 'Jan' || element === 'Feb') {
    console.log('woot');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this? Make an array with the data that you want.. and go through the array with a foreach ?

```js
var months = ['Jan','Feb','Apr','Jul','Sep'];
months.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element +  " - " + "quarter1");
});
```